# postion one Imageview below another - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a problem right now to position an imageview below another imageview. Despite i have used  android:layout_below nothing seems to happend. I have done this before with succes. The only thing I can think of right now is that this imageview holds and image that is rather big (width 500sp , height 750sp).

The id's of the three imageview are as follows - two small views

1) single
2) volume
3) extraImage (this is the view that holds the large image)

And I want to put extraImage below single

here is the xml syntax

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="5dp"
  android:paddingLeft="0px"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="0px"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  tools:context=".PhraseActivity" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/single"
    android:layout_width="68sp"
    android:layout_height="68sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />



  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/extraImage"
    android:layout_width="500sp"
    android:layout_height="750sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/single"
   />


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/volume"
    android:layout_width="50sp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   />
</RelativeLaoyout>
```

And here is how I want it

[image]

And here is how it is at the moment

[image]

**SO MY QUESTION: HOW DO I FIX THIS PROBLEM - HOW DO I POSITION THE LARGE IMAGEVIEW BELOW THE SMALL ONE (single)?**

I have also tried  with android:layout_toEndOf="" without success

Comment: are you using relative layout ??

Comment: @mohammedmomn yes - all childs are wrapped inside a RelativeLayout

Comment: Please show your entire xml file

Comment: @Aamirkhan - I have updated my code - now you can see the full version

Answer (score 0):

Try putting ImageView1 and ImageView2 in a horizontal LinearLayout then it should work.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single"
        android:layout_width="68sp"
        android:layout_height="68sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/volume"
        android:layout_width="50sp"
        android:layout_height="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/extraImage"
    android:layout_width="500sp"
    android:layout_height="750sp" />
```

Comment: I tried this but get compilation error that the layouts is not of the same siblings. The outer layout is relativeLayout and the inner (the one you suggested) linearLayout

Comment: That's right, it won't work with a RelativeLayout as parent. Can you replace your RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

look i try this and it give me the idea you need to make

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode the values of width and height. For top 2 images use weights equally Like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/single"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/volume"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/extraImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```